# static file taking time in seconds and minute over nginx server

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

this is my simple nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name perf.resume-search.com;
        root <path to rood dircetoru>;
        index index.html;


        location / {
       try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
       }
}
```

but it take lot of time to load simple css and js file.

http://perf.resume-search.com/js/react.js

taking 1 min approx to download 1 mb js file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIEJ2.png)

Comment: Do you check internet connection speed? you can download your js file with curl in local to see the problem is from internet or nginx.

Comment: did you solve this?